# creating new variable name instance using this[ ] in actionscript 3

Tags: variables, actionscript, this, instance, movieclip

I keep looking this over the internet but I think, as far as I have searched, nothing yet had been posted (if any, please give me some links). Is this a way to make an instance this way. When I tried, there's a compilation error, a syntax error ("expecting identifier before this"). I'm happy to receive help from you guys.

Here's my code.

```
var mc_Names:Array = [];

function createMovieClip(index:int):void{
    var nameOfMc:String = "mc_" + index;
    mc_Names[index] = nameOfMc;
    var this[mc_Names[index]]:MovieClip = new MovieClip();       **// this is what I'm asking if it is possible**
    this[mc_Names[index]].graphics.lineStyle(20,0x00FF00, 0.5);
    this[mc_Names[index]].graphics.moveTo(square_mc.x,square_mc.y);
    this[mc_Names[index]].graphics.lineTo(mc3.x, mc3.y);
    this[mc_Names[index]].x = 0;
    this[mc_Names[index]].y = 0;
    addChildAt(this[mc_Names[index]], 0);
    currentIndex++;
}
```

Or is there any way to make it more simple or another way of declaring variable instances through this[] to make a dynamic creation of those movieclip instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index:int = 1;
var A:Array = new Array();
A[index] = "mc_1";
A[index] = new MovieClip();
A[index].graphics.lineStyle(20,0x00FF00, 0.5);
A[index].graphics.moveTo(0,0);
A[index].graphics.lineTo(100, 100);
A[index].x = 0;
A[index].y = 0;
addChildAt(A[index], 0);
```

//it is possible to do this way. Direct substitution... :D